# SQL order and limit on a result of a query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that gets rows ordered by **column a** and limited to 100. Then I want to run a query on that result that gets rows ordered by **column b** and limited by 50.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the first `order by`/`limit` in a derived table. Then do the second `order by`/`limit` on the derived table's result:

```
select * from
(
select * from tablename
order by a
limit 100
) dt
order by b
limit 50
```

Comment: The "dt" is important, I am going to select this as the correct answer once I am allowed to select a correct answer.

Comment: Yes, some dbms products need that dt, but I can never remember which ones... (Optional according to the ANSI SQL standard.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `select from select` statement:

```
select a, b
from (
   select a, b
   from table1
   order by a
   limit 100
)
order by b
limit 50
```